# Recreate Contact List in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

So here is the long and silly backstory:

One of our users has lived exclusively in Microsoft Outlook 2010 and has several years worth of email addresses stored in his contact list. A recent server change caused some weird glitch and he lost all of his contacts and calendar entries. I re-imported his .pst file from a backup on our server, but apparently the contacts and calendar entries weren't stored in there?

I have no idea what to do to recover that data for him, but it's a massive blow for him to lose that information.

One idea that I had would be to somehow populate his address book with all of the emails that were recovered from the pst backup. Does anything like this exist?

Is there some secret area of the computer that contact information is automatically stored that I just don't know about?

Some facts:

1. We're not using an exchange server. Outlook is merely acting as an email client for our IMAP server.
2. I'm not a systems administrator. I'm just a software engineer that got asked to try and fix this. It could very well be that there's just something really simple that I've missed that would fix everything.
3. The pst files are backed up on a Drobo. They have a weird file extension and timestamp, but simply changing the extension to .pst seemed to work at importing the mail (even though it excluded the calendar and contacts).

Comment: There might be more pst files to restore than the ones you have found. I also don't like their having a "weird file extension and timestamp" - could you give an example?

Comment: Well, it's being backed up in two different file names depending on the day of the month. It's all either whatever.pst.TIMESTAMP.alt or whatever.pst.TIMESTAMP.dlt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea about recreating the contacts list from the email messages stored on the PST files would work. For this you can use [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) to export the sender email addresses to an Excel file or to a CSV (Comma delimited) file.

Outlook can import the contacts from a CSV file:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295664

[image: Export email parts]

[image: MailExporter extraction job]

You can find further information about MsgExtract exporting features here:

http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)

Comment: Disclaimer or not, if this works, I'm going to name my next child after you. I'll give it a try today at lunch and let you know if it works. Thanks. <3

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. For posterity, everyone should be aware that you need to purchase the Professional license. I bought the standard version first and it didn't have the right functionality. :( Other than that, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The user probably stored their contacts in a different PST file. Have a look to see if there were any other PSTs associated with the user. Try using something like [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro) to search for PST files and search inside them for known contact information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. He did have two separate PSTs, but I've imported both of them and none of them contain his calendar and contact information. I've also run scanpst.exe on both of them hoping that maybe there was just a corruption or something, but no luck. :(

Comment: Have you checked the local file system for a PST file?

Comment: Yeah. Only found the two PSTs. The drobo backup server is just taking copies of those two files that are stored on the local system.

Comment: Apologies for stating the obvious but you have checked both in the Contacts tab haven't you? They'll be stored in some PST somewhere.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure I did. I've imported both of them at the same time and checked in the Contacts tab after each import and they are empty after each one. It doesn't make any sense to me either. :(

Comment: Just as a small test, try creating a dummy contact in BOTH PST contact folders, just to make sure the PST is working properly.